# How to implement a smart maintenance page for nginx that appears when the underlying server is down?

Tags: nginx

I am looking for a nginx solution that would display a temporary down message when the underling server is down.

I am looking or a solution that would behave like this:

- display a maintenance page (503) if the upstream server is down
- display a timeout (504) if the upstream server did not return any content in 60 seconds (it could take more to return the entire content)
- optionally: find a way of measuring the time spend from when the service went down first time so I can display a maintenance message: but send an email to the admin if this still happens for more than 5 minutes.

To reiterate, the whole point is to make a config that allows the server administrator to restart the upstream servers without having to manage the maintenance messages.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of [5031818](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031818/show-a-custom-503-page-if-upstream-is-down), plus using something like http://pingdom.com

Answer (score 0):

If you set the timeout values for proxy or fcgi requests (depending on your setup) to your liking, you can indeed use the `error_page` directive to configure different error pages for specific error codes.

[The nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) has the details, as already pointed out by [kashyap](https://stackoverflow.com/users/662530/kashyap).

Your optional requirement basically amounts to a monitoring service, this is not something best done inside a frontend server, most likely.